# Go cannot create RabbitMQ channel. RabbitMQ server on docker container, Go script on host

Tags: go, docker, rabbitmq

I'm running a RabbitMQ server on a docker container and I'm not able to open a RabbitMQ channel from the host machine.

The docker container is run from the RabbitMQ image this way, forwarding management ports and amqp port to the host :

```
docker run -d -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 --hostname my-rmq --name rmq rabbitmq:3-management
```

The channel part of the go script is pretty straightforward :

```
ch, err := conn.Channel()
failOnErrorRmq(err, "Failed to open a channel")
defer ch.Close()
```

And I'm getting the following error

```
Failed to open a channel: write tcp [::1]:51937->[::1]:5672: use of closed network connection
```

I'm new to RabbitMQ. Any help on using RabbitMQ with Docker would be great.